# How do I make this plugin generator work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, generator

First of all I am new to rails. I want to make a country.list table in my database so I found a great plugin on github at https://github.com/mm1/country-list so I kind of figured out how to install it. I ran the following command in my application root: `rails plugin install https://github.com/mm1/country-list` which installed the plugin inside the vendor/plugins folder. Now I want to use it to generate a country-list table, how do I make it work?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you're trying to use is very old. Try something like [carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen). It's compatible with the version of Rails you're targeting and has a lot of nice features.

Answer (score 0):

run rake db:migrate and you will have a model country for using the plugin.
so you can use this model's attribute anywhere you want like

A smentioned in the site the attributes of the model country are name, iso2, iso3 and numeric for ISO 3166

so anywhere you want to use this model, you can give something like

```
country = Country.all
country_name = country.find(id).name # id can be any unique attribute
```

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate but I did not get a country model. The question is how do I use the plugin. I mean do I just copy and paste the migration file? or do I run some kind of generator?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code, the generator does not actually do very much. You can easily recreate these steps manually. This is what it does:

```
# check if "migrate" folder exists
#if not then create the folder
migrations_directory_path = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/migrate"
Dir.mkdir(migrations_directory_path) unless File.directory?(migrations_directory_path)

#copy countries migration
record do |m|
  m.file 'migrations/create_countries.rb', "db/migrate/{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}_create_countries.rb"
end
```

All it's doing is copying a migration file to the new location! You can do this yourself in line from irb:

```
File.copy("plugins/country-list/generators/countries_list/templates/migrations/create_countries.rb", "db/migrate/#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}_create_countries.rb")
```

And the supplied model doesn't actually contain anything, it's just a skeleton:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But how do you run this generator if you would like to? I mean the rails generate command doesn't do it...